# R Geocode with google with search restrictions to a country

Tags: r, google-geocoder

I am trying to filter out the search results to be from a certain country only since at times the API returns random latitude and longitude. Here is the code I have

```
library(ggmap)

# Select the file from the file chooser
#fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable 
register_google(key = "xxxxxxx")
origAddress <- read.csv("test.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude of each address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress)) {
  result <- tryCatch(geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google"),
                     warning = function(w) data.frame(lon = NA, lat = NA, address = NA))
  origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3]

  )
}
# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I have edited the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the code working.

```
library(ggmap)

# Select the file from the file chooser
#fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable 
register_google(key = "xxxxxxx")
origAddress <- read.csv("test.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude of each address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress)) {
  result <- tryCatch(geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google", inject = paste ("components = country =" , origAddress$country[i])),
                     warning = function(w) data.frame(lon = NA, lat = NA, address = NA))
  origAddress$lon[i]`enter code here` <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3]

  )
}
# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```